# How do they decide the value of a cryptocurrency?

Tags: blockchain

How is the dollar value of a new cryptocurrency determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offer and demand. That's why it varies slightly depending on the market place.

Comment: Thanks. So why would anyone want /demand for a completely new cryptocurrency?

Comment: Speculators, early adopters, gamblers willing to take risks, people who support a given property of the new currency (privacy for Zcash for instance)...